# Selenium-Server and Selenium to test a service that is NOT web enabled

Tags: selenium

Our development team is developing a service (NOT web enabled) to support our web enabled application.  I test the web part with Selenium/JUnit/Eclipse/Java.

I was wondering if there is anyway to use Selenium-Server / Selenium to test a service that is not web enabled?

Anyone ever attempted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Selenium isn't for testing services, its for testing web GUIs
2. If it's not web-enabled then how will you access the service ?

Look at [soapui](http://www.soapui.org/) for web service testing